# Django cart_add cart.py Don't show items

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to create cart in my django-shop.i start new app named cart and add new file to this app **cart.py**. In this file i created class Cart and add some function. 
This is cart.py

```
class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        """

         Inicjaliazacja koszyka na zakupy.
        """
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            # pusty koszyk w sesji
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False, size=None, upd_size=False):
        """
         Dodanie produktu i zmiana ilości
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'size': None,
                                     'price': str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        if upd_size:
            self.cart[product_id]['size'] = size
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['size'] += size
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        """
        Usunięcie produktów z koszyka
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Iteracja przez elementy na zakupy i pobranie z bazy danych
        """

        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Obliczanie liczby wszytskich elementów w koszyku.
        """
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        # usunięcie koszyka
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.session.modified = True
```

Next i created file (forms.py) and add this code:

```
from django import forms

PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 21)]

SIZE_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'S'),
    ('M', 'M'),
    ('L', 'L'),
    ('XL', 'XL')
)


class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(
                                choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES,
                                coerce=int)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                                initial=False,
                                widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    sz = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=SIZE_CHOICES,
        initial=False)
```

My next step was to create views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from shop.models import Product
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 update_quantity=cd['update'],
                 size=cd['size'],
                 upd_size=['sz'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(
                      initial={'quantity': item['quantity'],
                               'update': True,
                               'size': item['size'],
                               'sz': True}
        )
    return render(request,
                  'cart/detail.html',
                  {'cart': cart})
```

and the last is thid detail.html in cart app:

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}{{ product.name }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        {% for item in cart %}
            {% with product=item.product %}
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                        <img src="{{ product.image_url }}" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
                {{product.name}}
                <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
                    {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
                    {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Zmień">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                </form>
                {{ item.quantity }}
                {{ item.size }}
                <a href="{% url 'cart:cart_remove' product.id%}">Usuń</a>
                {{item.price}}
                {{item.total_price}}
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
        {{cart.get_total_price}}

        <a href="{% url 'orders:order_create' %}">
            Do kasy
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I add form in poduct detail.html to add product in cart.

What's going wrong?
When i click add to cart moves me to cart/detail.html but nothing show.
When i deleted evrything with size that's work good and show me product in cart/detail.html without size but i need it. How I can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

There's typo in your views.

There should be cd['sz'], not ['sz']

It is now:

```
if form.is_valid():
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    cart.add(product=product,
             quantity=cd['quantity'],
             update_quantity=cd['update'],
             size=cd['size'],
             upd_size=['sz'])
return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

It should be

```
if form.is_valid():
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    cart.add(product=product,
             quantity=cd['quantity'],
             update_quantity=cd['update'],
             size=cd['size'],
             upd_size=cd['sz'])
return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

Comment: Also, I think you've mixed purpose of fields 'size' and 'sz'. In your CartAddProductForm you should change field name from 'sz' to 'size', and change initial to somevalid size (specified in SIZE_CHOICES).